# Overload resolution with templates and rvalue references

Tags: c++, c++11, overload-resolution

This overload resolution behavior baffles me:

```
#include "stdio.h"

template<class T>
class C
{
public:
    C(T v): m(v) {};
    T m;
    template<class U>
    T f(U &&p)
    {
        printf("rRef called.\n");
        return p;
    }

    template<class U>
    T f(const U &p)
    {
        printf("const Ref called.\n");
        return p;
    }
};

int main()
{
    C<int> a(5);
    a.f<int&>(a.m);
    a.f(a.m);
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
const Ref called.
rRef called.
```

When debugging in gdb or Visual Studio, both debuggers show
`int C<int>::f<int &>()` called in both cases, but the explicit template resolution resolves to the expected const ref, while the second resolves to a rvalue reference. Why? Why doesn't the compiler even try
`int C<int>::f<int>()` which I thought would be the obvious match?
How can a rvalue reference bind to a member value? Isn't `a.m` a lvalue?

Comment: `U &&` is not an rvalue reference, but a [forwarding reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references) in this instance, which can bind to anything.  I'm more surprised by `a.f<int&>(a.m)` calling the const-ref version.

Answer (score 2):

When you make the call:

```
a.f<int&>(a.m);
```

the compiler has to choose between the following candidates:

```
template<class U>
T f(U && p);       // #1

template<class U>
T f(U const & p);  // #2
```

For this overload resolution process, first both templates are transformed for the parameter `int&`.

Substituting `U = int &` for `#1` gives `int & &&`, which due to reference collapsing, becomes `int &`.

Similarly, substituting `U = int &` for `#2` gives `int & const &`, which again due to reference collapsing, becomes `int &`.

Now, since both overloads match, partial ordering is used to determine which template to call. Now `U const &` is more *specialized* than `U &&`. This is because `U &&` can bind to all the types that `U const &` can, but the converse is not true.

Hence, since `#2` is more specialized, it wins in overload resolution, and gets called.

---

In this call:

```
a.f(a.m);
```

the template parameter is *not* specified. This means the parameter of `#1` is considered to be a forwarding reference, and this matches all types that are passed in, and so `#1` gets called.

Comment: Hold on. *"This matches exactly"* - So would the overload with the forwarding reference, `int & &&` becomes `int &`. Matching exactly doesn't seem to be the key here.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Yes, the forwarding reference matches, but is only chosen as a last resort, I thought.

Comment: Mmm, no, that's not how it works. It's a candidate like any other, always. This is likely due to partial ordering, not due to it being a forwarding reference directly.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Oh, so there's something more subtle about overload resolution I'm missing here then?

Comment: If `U` is explicitly specified `U &&` is no longer a forwarding reference, but a regular rvalue reference as far as I know.

Comment: @IlCapitano Oh, if that's the case, then my answer is plain wrong.

Comment: @cigien - Yes. Partial ordering is at play, definitely. https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/temp.func.order - If memory serves (because I didn't parse it in full), the forwarding overload can always deduce a function generated from the second, while the converse isn't true. That's why it's picked, it's more specialized in this case.

Comment: @IlCapitano - If `U` is specified to be a lvalue reference type, then `U &&` is also an lvalue reference, by reference collapsing.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Yes, I meant that `&&` no longer has a special meaning if you explicitly specify `U`.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Yes, you're right. Both candidates work, but `T const&` is strictly more specialized than `T&&`, so partial ordering chooses that. I'll fix the answer.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Ok, I've fixed the answer, I hope :)

Comment: @IlCapitano Fixed the answer :)

Comment: Thank you all for spending time on this. I still do not quite get 2 things:
1. Isn't the type of a.m "int"? Why do we start toking about "int &" before considering int?
2. Why in the case when the type is not explicitly specified the second overload is not even considered?

Comment: @C.Szabo 1. When the parameter is specified, that's the type that's used (the type of the argument is only considered after). 2. Because forwarding references will catch everything.